# Passing elements to function efficiently

Tags: python, function, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have an array of size m x n. 
I want to pass each m row individually to a function and save the result in the same row.

What would be the efficient way of doing this using numpy.
Currently I am using for loops to achieve this:

```
X : size(m x n)
p : size(m x n)

for i in np.arange(X.shape[0]):
    X[i] = some_func(X[i], p[i])
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass both the array and the number of row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are modifying the row of `X`, you can skip the indexing and use `zip` to iterate on the rows:

```
In [833]: X=np.ones((2,3)); p=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)                         
In [834]: for x,y in zip(X,p): 
     ...:     x[:] = x + y 
     ...:                                                                       
In [835]: X                                                                     
Out[835]: 
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 5., 6.]])
```

If you still needed the index you could add enumerate:

```
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(X,p)):...
```

There isn't much difference in efficiency in these alternatives.  You still have to call your function `m` times.  You still have to select rows, either by index or by iteration.  Both are a bit slower on arrays than on the equivalent list.

The best thing is to write your function so it works directly with the 2d arrays, and doesn't need iteration.

```
X+p
```

But if the function is too complex for that, then its evaluation time is likely to be relatively high (compared to the iteration mechanism).

Comment: That is what I ended up doing in the end. Just had to upgrade my function.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of all first row of the X and p Matrix using List Comprehension as shown below. Then you can easily send the first row of X and p as a parameters to your `some_function`

```
import numpy as np

X =  np.random.randint(9, size=(3, 3))
p =  np.random.randint(9, size=(3, 3))

print(X.shape, p.shape)

XList = [i[0] for i in X]
pList = [j[0] for j in p]

print (XList)
print (pList)

for i in np.arange(XList, pList):
    X[i] = some_func(XList, pList)
```

Comment: It is the same as using for loops. I wanted to know if there was some other way of doing this using numpy.